# Java GPA Program Issue

Tags: java

My program for some reason is calculating the GPA average wrong. If I enter 4.0 three times, then it says the average GPA is 3.0 but should be 4.0. Can someone help me find the issue?

```
//variables
double gpa = 0;
double total = 0;
int counter = 0;
int counter2 = 0;

do
{
    String gpaEntry = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter GPAs:");
    gpa = Double.parseDouble(gpaEntry);

    if (gpa >= 3.5)
        counter2 ++;

    total += gpa;
        counter ++;
}
while (gpa != 0);

double average = (double) (total/counter);

JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The Average GPA is: " + average);
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Number of students:" + counter2);
```

Comment: Does the 0 count as an entry?

Comment: I don't want it to. I would like for the 0 to stop the entering of GPAs and then continue with the program.

Comment: Ok, and why don't you do that?

Comment: I thought I did. Can you provide a hint to as how to fix the issue?

Comment: Step through your code with pen and paper. What happens after you enter 0?

Comment: It should stop the do loop and start calculating the average.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's walk through the code

- gpa = 0
- get user input (user enters '2')
- now gpa = 2
- total += 2
- counter ++
- while(gpa != 0) // nope, gpa is 2
- loop back
- get user input (user enters '0')
- now gpa = 0
- total += 0
- counter ++ // oops!
- while(gpa != 0) // yep, quit the loop

but it's too late, we already incremented `counter`, so our `average` calculation is wrong

Comment: So should I use an if / else statement to check to see if it's a 0 and then continue with the program?

Comment: There are several ways to fix it. 1) move/duplicate the user entry code as @ikhalq15 did. 2) add `if(gpa==0) break` after you get user input 3) or `if(gpa!=0)counter++` 4) do `counter--` after your loop is done.

Comment: Thank you!! I used option 2.

Comment: One more question, if I use the if(gpa==0) break option. What do I do about the while (gpa != 0) at the end of my code?

Comment: you don't actually need it any more, you can change it to `while(true)`

Answer (score 0):

What is wrong is that if a user enters 0, then it runs the program and then exits.

Try this code (Sorry, I do not have an editor at the moment so you might have to fix some small thing).

```
//variables
double gpa = 0;
double total = 0;
int counter = 0;
int counter2 = 0;

String gpaEntry = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter GPAs:");
gpa = Double.parseDouble(gpaEntry);

while (gpa != 0) {
    if (gpa >= 3.5)
        counter2 ++;

    total += gpa;
    counter ++;

    gpaEntry = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter GPAs:");
    gpa = Double.parseDouble(gpaEntry);
}

JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The Average GPA is: " + average);
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Number of students:" + counter2);
```

Comment if you have any more questions.